# How to use grey text so that it prints nicely on a B&W laserprinter?

Tags: graphics, color, printing

In my latex document, I have a chart (created through matplotlib, and saved as .pdf file), where I put some text in grey. This is fine  when looking at the paper PDF onscreen (its a vector image, so it is crisp clear).

However, when I print the paper on a B&W laserprinter, the grey text is emulated using small black dots. The result is that the text doesn't look very nice (see slightly fuzzy photo below, it's about `CS prefereable` and `PS preferable`), and depending on the (down)scaling I use in latex, it is even close to unreadable.

Is there a 'proper' way to have grey text in charts (that will be used in a latex document) so that they come out fine when printing as well?

[image: Photo of chart with grey text]

Comment: It's probably a matter for your print driver rather than your output (and therefore technically off-topic). But what happens if zoom right in on the PDF on screen?  I'm assuming you get solid grey.  Try changing the "quality", "dpi" or "mode:economy/normal/..." settings on your print driver, and also any options regarding downloading fonts.  You could also see what happens if you generate a bitmap with a similar shade of grey and print that - ideally in a PDF.

Comment: Indeed, the line is solid grey. But a co-author printing my paper at his university has the exact same issue. So fixing the printer driver would only fix it for me... :-(

Comment: What is your printer model, OS and what driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be a second comment, but turned out too long, so I  incorporated my original comment and expanded further.

It's probably a matter for your print driver rather than your output (and therefore technically off-topic). But what happens if zoom right in on the PDF on screen? I'm assuming you get solid grey. Try changing the "quality", "dpi" or "mode:economy/normal/..." settings on your print driver, and also any options regarding downloading fonts.

While it is true that changing the printer driver settings is a local fix, if they are the problem, you have no choice.  Fundamentally a (typical) laser printer can only print pure black and white, any grey must be printed by some form of [halftoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftoning) and control of that is likely to be beyond the scope of a document format.

You could also see what happens if you generate a bitmap with a similar shade of grey and print that - ideally in a PDF. As the printer driver may well handle bitmap and raster data differently this may appear to offer a way out, but it will cause more problems than it solves.

In cases such as your example, you may find that a darker grey or a colour (often 100% red or blue) would provide an adequate workaround, or even, as you've used italics already, just use black.

Incidentally, how is the graph produced and displayed in your latex file - I'm guessing it's an image, but what format?